# C# - Change title of another Form

Tags: c#, forms, title

How can I change title of Form 1 from my From 2? Here is my code:

Form1:

```
public void setTitle(string title)
    {
        this.Text = title;
    }
```

Form2:

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1= new Form1();
        f1.setTitle(textBoxTitle.Text);
        this.Hide();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass Form1 as parameter in Form2's constructor.

```
Form1 Form_one;

public Form2(Form1 form1):this()
{
  Form_one = form1;
}

private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Form_one.setTitle(textBoxTitle.Text);
 this.Hide();
}
```

In the method you want to show Form2 you should call like that;

```
Form2(this).Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the actual instance of Form1 which is currently displayed.

While displaying Form1, keep an instance to it in Form2. (I am assuming that you are displaying Form1 from Form2. If not, you should provide that Form1 instance to Form2 while creating an instance of Form2)

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 form1;

    private void OpenForm1()
    {
        form1 = new Form1();
        form.Show()
    }
}
```

Then, invoke the setTitle() on that instance:

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.setTitle(textBoxTitle.Text);
    this.Hide();
}
```